# Should a UK address form have 2 or 3 address lines fields?

Tags: website-design, signup-signon, addresses

In my mind it makes sense for a UK address form to contain 3 address lines.  There are instances of people living in blocks or buildings where 2 lines may not always be enough.

I just wondered if anyone had any thoughts and/or guidance on this, should a UK address form have 2 or 3 address lines fields?

Best practice and thoughts are all welcome.

Comment: [Falsehoods programmers believe about addresses](http://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/)

Comment: Also have a look here: http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2008/06/international-address-fields-in-web-forms.php

Comment: @BartGijssens: Good article. And written by LukeW too, so if anyone knows about web forms it's him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the address itself, there should be 4 lines as explained on [the clear addressing guidelines on the official Royal Mail website](http://www.royalmail.com/personal/help-and-support/How-do-I-address-my-mail-correctly) (I say for the address itself because there is 4 **+ 1** line for the addressee's name).
**EDIT :** Some people have pointed out to me that you sometimes need to indicate the house name before the street name, so 5 lines instead of 4 finally !

Comment: Except that if you have a house **name** this is often put on its own line before the street name, which makes five lines (that example is not included in RM guidance). And many people still like to include the county.

Comment: Is putting the house name necessary or not ?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise Yes, putting the building name is necessary; if you live in a flat for example.

Comment: Putting the house name is certainly necessary if the street is not numbered. This is often the case in more rural areas.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my post in consequence then... I am asking myself one question :
What do you guys think about replacing the several text fields by one text area (with a placeholder to give the example to the user) just as It would be when you write a real letter ?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise That would be good, except the post town and post code should be in separate fields if you need to extract that information then ask for county as a separate fields as it is after the post town. However if non UK the all these fields might not exist - see the link in JonW's comment - note also some people don't know their "correct" address but give a form that will get to them

Comment: a UK address can have 8 elements, plus country, see "five lines and country will cover all cases" on https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/